# Video Player component not working in hdrp project

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, rendering, textures

I'm using Unity 2019.3.0a2 and created the project with the HDRP settings, at my scene I have a plane with a material using an HDRP/lit shader, the plane contains the video player component and the render mode is set to "material Override" the renderer target is the same of the plane and the material property is  "_MainTex".

Problem is I see no video I can only hear the audio, video properties are as follows:
format .mp4, length 6:00, size: 1280x720, 30fps.

I already updated to the latest unity version, also to the latest High definition rendering pipeline available which for me is v6.5.3 and still no video is there any fix for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following in HDRP:

1. Create a new material
2. Change the material Shader to HDRP/Unlit
3. Drag and drop your RenderTexture onto Surface Inputs --> Color

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The HDRP/Lit shader does not have a "_MainTex" property. The property you want to render to is "_BaseColorMap".

Change the `Material Property` value to "_BaseColorMap".

Comment: Done but still the same no image just sound,

Comment: Following your logic I changed the material type to HDRP/Unlit and selected "_UnlitColorMap" at the material property but video is "too white" can barely see the video

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, apparently the best approach is to make a render texture and on the video player you select "Render Texture" and place the newly created "render texture", at the material you just need to place that same texture in the albedo, the details are in the video.

https://youtu.be/KG2aq_CY7pU

Comment: The question is about HDRP but this answer and the video link provided won't work with HDRP (HDRP Shaders don't have an albedo option). Please see my answer below